# Oracle DataPump Exports in Different Charset

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following warning on Datapump export from my Oracle database:

```
Export done in WE8ISO8859P1 character set and UTF8 NCHAR character set
server uses UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
```

This is causing (I believe) the following export warning:

```
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
```

My `$NLS_LANG` environment variable is set to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`. The database is in `UTF8` for everything (local and national).

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your NLS_LANG setting isn't making it to the export. Is this export local (on the machine with the database) or client/server ? Is it being scheduled through cron or through some other spawned process ?

Comment: It is a local export scheduled through cron.

Comment: cron might not initiate the same setup commands. Do you get the same message if you run export directly from a command prompt ? If not, then its a cron/environment issue.

Comment: Hi Gary-it turns out cron was not picking up the environment variable. If you could move your comment to the answers I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my NLS_LANG setting wasn't making it to the export, since `cron` wasn't picking it up. Thanks @Gary (if you move your answer to the comments I'll accept that one instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `statistics=NONE` parameter for expdp to avoid this error. Statistics can be recalculated later using `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS();`.

Or set `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1` as you database seems to use this character set (find out by querying `NLS_CHARACTERSET` from `nls_database_parameters` or `nls_session_parameters`).